# How can I set this precommit msg hook for Github?

Tags: regex, git, github

I would like to force all developers who commit to my **private Github** repo to always add a commit message that follows this syntax:

```
[ticketid] description
```

- *ticketid* can be an unlimited number of letters or numbers surrounded by [ ] brackets
- *description* can be unlimited free text

Empty comments are not allowed. Both values are mandatory.

**Valid** example commit message:

> [dk93jled] Changed headline color to red

**Invalid** example commit message (Description text missing, ticketid not in brackets):

> dk93jled

Also **invalid** (ticketid missing):

> Changed headline color to red

Also **invalid** (No brackets):

> dk93jled Changed headline color to red

---

**Question:**

How can I implement the requirement above? I smell regular expressions here so please add a full working regex to your answer because I really suck when it comes up to regular expressions :-(

Also, I need instructions on how to add this regex to Github in order to work.

Comment: You really would need to specify in more detail the format, because based on your specification, the **invalid** commit message is valid and has:

ticketId = `Changed`, description = `headline color to red`.

(I.e. "Changed" matches the specification for a ticket-id being "an unlimited number of letters or numbers").

In fact, any two-word-commit-message (even if it is just two letters separated by a space) matches your requirement.

Comment: @Alderath Oh, snap. You're right, thanks! I fixed that in my question.

Comment: I have to believe that the two questions here (how to add a pre-commit hook and how to match an arbitrary string in brackets) have been independently, _exhaustively_ answered both on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: `^\[\w*?\]\s(?:\w+\s?)+$` I'll leave the regex for when you have to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a client-side commit hook `.git/hooks/commit-msg` with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

check=$(head -1 $1 | egrep '^\[\w*?\]\s(\w+\s?)+$')
if [ "" = "$check" ]; then
        echo "Commit message invalid." 1>&2
        echo "Required format:" 1>&2
        echo "    [ticketid] description" 1>&2
        exit 1
fi
```

**Note:** This will NOT enforce it upon developers who do not add the above code on their own repo.

Comment: simple and perfect,
I used my own regex for this format `Chore | As a [User], I want to ...` with this regex `(Feature|Fix|Perf|Docs|Style|Refactor|Test|Chore)\s\|\sAs (a|an)\s\[(User|View|System)\],\s.*`